# hibernate and drop table

Tags: hibernate, orm

what happen if hibernate has a reference to table X, and then I rename table X to Y, rename table Z to X? 
would it cause an exception in hibernate when clients try to access existing data?  any pitfalls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the mappings are correct for a given table, it doesn't matter how the table was created (i.e. whether it was another table renamed). Perhaps use `hbm2ddl.auto=validate` option to let hibernate check whether everything is OK when it starts.